# (Infinite) Nested radical equation, how to get the right solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been tasked with coming up with exam questions for a high school math contest to be hosted at my university. I offer the following equation,
$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-\cdots}}}}=2$$
and ask for the solution for $x$.

Here's what I attempted so far. The first utilizes some pattern recognition, but it gives me two solutions (only one of which is correct).
$$\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-\cdots}}}}&=2\\
\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-\cdots}}}&=4-x\\
\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-\cdots}}&=x-(4-x)^2\\
2&=x-(4-x)^2&\text{(from line 1)}\\
(x-6)(x-3)&=0
\end{align*}$$
$x=6$ is the extraneous solution. Where did I go wrong, and how can I fix this?

I know there's a closed form for non-alternating nested radicals $\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\cdots}}$ and $\sqrt{n-\sqrt{n-\cdots}}$, but I can't seem to find anything on alternating signs.

Comment: Nothing went wrong anywhere. Your implications lead from the top to the bottom, the proof should be in reverse. It's just unfinished.

Comment: But with $x=6$, I find the LHS to converge to $2.79129\ldots$. How would one approach the equation so as to only get a solution of $x=3$?

Comment: Just a sanity check: Do you know what $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-\ldots}}$ actually means? How is it defined?

Comment: You need $x<4$ for the positive square root to be valid.

Comment: In the second line, ......$=4-x$. The LHS is a square root which is positive. So $x<4$. After you take the square $(4-x)^2$, you introduced an extra root, which should be rejected at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with that kind of expression with nested radicals is that the rigorous meaning of the "$\ldots$" at the end is not always clear (and I presume that's what some people were trying to point out in the comments).

In this case, I think you are considering the sequence given by $x_1 = \sqrt{x}$ and $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x - x_n}}$ (for some fixed $x \geq 0$) and asking for values of $x$ for which $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 2$.

The first thing to be worried about here is whether it's safe to take $\sqrt{x - x_n}$, that is, whether $x_n \leq x$. For $0 < x < 1$ everything goes south as $x_1 = \sqrt{x} > x$. For $x > 1$, $x_1 = \sqrt{x}$ is ok, but $x_2 = \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x - \sqrt{x}}}$ can be a problem if $x$ is small (try $x = 1.1$); to avoid these issues, let us assume $x \geq 2$, when clearly $x_n \leq \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x}} < x$.

Secondly, does $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ always exist if $x \geq 2$? Yes it does, because the sequence is clearly increasing (why?) and bounded above by $\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x}}$ (why?).

Since the limit exists, we can call it $L = L(x)$: it satisfies the inequality $\sqrt{x} \leq L \leq \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x}}$ and the equation $L = \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x - L}}$, so that $L^4 - 2L^2x + L + x^2 - x = 0$.

Which values of $x$ could possibly have $L(x) = 2$? Well, they must satisfy $x^2 - 9x + 18 = 0$, so that $x = 3$ or $x = 6$. On the other hand, since $x$ also must satisfy $\sqrt{x} \leq 2$ (or $x \leq 4$), the solution $x = 6$ can be discarded.

What about $x = 3$, can it be proclaimed "the winner"? Not quite yet, we must verify that $L(3) = 2$: for that, we check that there are no other viable candidates for $L(3)$. To see this, notice that $L(3)$ must be a root of
$L^4 - 6L^2 + L + 6 = (L+1)(L-2)(L^2 + L - 3)$. Since $2$ is the only root satisfying $\sqrt{3} \leq 2 \leq \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}}$, we can safely say $L(3) = 2$, and $x = 3$ is the only solution to the original problem.

Comment: +1, Finally someone who understands! (but maybe I shouldn't have been so lazy and should have written an answer myself)

Answer (score 5):

You know that:

$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-\cdots}}}}=A = 2$$

and hence

$$A = \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-A}} = 2$$

or equivalently

$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-2}} = 2$$

Clearly, $\sqrt{x-2}$ is well defined when $$x \geq 2. ~~~(1)$$
Then, squaring both side, you get:

$$x+ \sqrt{x-2} = 4 \Rightarrow \sqrt{x-2} = 4-x ~~~(2).$$

Since $\sqrt{x-2} \geq 0$, then also $4-x \geq0$, and hence

$$x \leq 4. ~~~(3)$$

Joining conditions $(1)$ and $(3)$, one obtain the existence set for $x$:

$$x \geq 2 \wedge x \leq 4 \Rightarrow 2\leq x \leq 4. ~~~(4)$$

Going back to $(3)$, we can square both side and we get:

$$x-2 = (4-x)^2 \Rightarrow x-2=16+x^2-8x \Rightarrow x^2-9x+18=0 \Rightarrow $$ $$\Rightarrow (x-3)(x-6) = 0. ~~~(5)$$

The solution of $(5)$ are $x_1 = 3$ and $x_2 = 6$, but according to $(4)$, only $x_1 = 3$ is feasible.

Comment: why downvote? Please, don't hide behind the hood!!!

Comment: Because you didn't check that $3$ actually is a solution. You can't just assume it out of the blue that there's a solution. For example, $x^2+1=0$ has no real solution. And this is especially needed when working with limits.

Comment: Ok... when $x=3$, then: $$\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3-2}} = \sqrt{3+\sqrt{1}} = \sqrt{4} = 2$$. When $x=6$, then:$$\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6-2}} = \sqrt{6+\sqrt{4}} = \sqrt{8} \neq 2$$

Comment: Not that, you have to check that $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3-\ldots}} = 2$. You only know that if this holds, then $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3-2}}=2$, but that's not enough!

Comment: Ok, indeed the way I solved the problem is like searching for the fixed point of the discrete time map $$y_{n+1} = \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-y_n}}$$. That is: $$y = \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x-y}}.$$ We want that $y=2$ is the fixed point and this happens only when $x=3$. This point converges if $\left|\frac{\partial y_{n+1}}{\partial y_{n}}\right| < 1$  evaluated for $y_n = y = 2$ and $x=3$. One get that $$\left.\frac{\partial y_{n+1}}{\partial y_{n}}\right|_{x=3, y_n=2}=-0.125,$$ so $y=2$ is attractive when $x=3$. Hence, the limit converges to $2$ when $x=3$.

Comment: @the_candyman Don't worry too much about the downvote: that is many members' lot here and nothing can be done because the site's administrators just don't care about it. The downvote is absurd in this case even if here and there some little inaccuracies/omissions exist. Perhaps one of the most interesting features of this problem is to prove the left hand in the original expression is well defined at all, meaning: the limit exists *finitely*. This was addressed in the other answer.

Comment: @Timbuc ok, thanks for the advice sir.

Answer (score 1):

In the second line, ......$=4-x$. The LHS is a square root which is positive. So $x<4$. After you take the square $(4-x)^2$, you introduced an extra root, which should be rejected at the end.

Comment: Still not finished. What if $x=3$ can be rejected too by some arcane manipulations?

Comment: 3<4, no need to reject.

Comment: You are missing my point. I didn't say that this rejects it, but what if you do more manipulations, subtract something, square, ... and it follows by other means that $x\ne 3$?

Comment: You are working from the beginning by  A --> B --> C --> D .....If you've done nothing wrong mathematically, it's impossible that the correct solution be ruled out from your final answer!!

Comment: In fact you final statement $x=3$ or $6$ is mathematically correct. 3 is the correct solution, 6 is not. So $x=3$ or $6$ is mathematically correct.

Comment: How do you know $3$ is the correct solution? What if there's none? That's still a valid answer to the question!

Comment: Suppose there is a solution, then you work step by step, one implying the other. And now you said that solution is ruled out in one of your steps, then your derivation is wrong!!

Comment: By the way, why downvote me?!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20401/discussion-between-user2345215-and-kyson).

Comment: user2345215, you are right